# OS Error [WinError 193]の解決方法を教えてください(keras-yolo3)

Tags: python

[実行環境]

- Windows10 64bit
- python 3.8.5 64bit
- anaconda 3.8.5
- pip 20.3
- tensorflow 2.3.1
- keras 2.4.3
- numpy 1.18.5
- cuda 10.1
- cuDNN 10.1

keras-yolo3を用いた顔を検出するための学習にあたって
タイトルにもありますエラーが発生したので解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

[出力内容]
※分かりやすいと思うのでJupitar notebookで実行したときの内容を書きました。
アナコンダプロンプト上で実行したときもおおよそ同じ内容のエラーが発生します。

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-be77ab001e17> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import keras.backend as K
      3 from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
      4 from keras.models import Model
      5 from keras.optimizers import Adam

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      1 
      2 try:
----> 3     from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
      4 except ImportError:
      5     raise ImportError(

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     45 from tensorflow.python import data
     46 from tensorflow.python import distribute
---> 47 from tensorflow.python import keras
     48 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
     49 from tensorflow.python.layers import layers

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     25 
     26 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
---> 27 from tensorflow.python.keras import models
     28 
     29 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import Input

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py in <module>
     24 from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
     25 from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers
---> 26 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional
     27 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import sequential
     28 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py in <module>
     36 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import keras_tensor
     37 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import node as node_module
---> 38 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training as training_lib
     39 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training_utils
     40 from tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model import network_serialization

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in <module>
     48 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer_utils
     49 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import compile_utils
---> 50 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import data_adapter
     51 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training_utils
     52 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision.experimental import loss_scale_optimizer as lso

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in <module>
     54 
     55 try:
---> 56   from scipy import sparse as scipy_sparse  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
     57 except ImportError:
     58   scipy_sparse = None

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>
    134 
    135     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 136     from . import _distributor_init
    137 
    138     from scipy._lib import _pep440

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     59             os.chdir(libs_path)
     60             for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(libs_path, '*dll')):
---> 61                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     62         finally:
     63             os.chdir(owd)

~\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    379 
    380         if handle is None:
--> 381             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    382         else:
    383             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 は有効な Win32 アプリケーションではありません。
```

Comment: イベントログにdll読み込みエラーが記録されてたりしませんか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます!もしかしたらあったかもしれないですね...。(今別の作業が忙しくてちゃんと見れてないですすいません..)もしdll読み込みエラーがあった場合はどうすればよいでしょうか

Comment: イベントログに記録があった場合は、記録されている内容を確認、判断すればいいと思います。

Comment: プログラムのコードが判らなくて、エラーメッセージだけで原因が判る訳がないです。ちゃんとエラーが起きたプログラムを提示してください。
質問のTracebackに　---> が付けられている行がありますが、ほとんどが import文で、「有効な Win32 アプリケーションではありません」というエラーが発生する可能性があると思われるコードは見当たりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

原因はよく分からなかったですが解決できました!
こちらのサイトが参考になったので載せておきます。
後はタイトルとか一部文章は編集しておきます。
回答してくださった方ありがとうございました!
https://qiita.com/tfukumori/items/d1f79078803d8a7fe103